# C# Socket BeginSend BeginReceive cause disconnect action

Tags: c#, sockets

There is a tcp connection established between client and server, the client side is using C# Socket. I found if server gets paused(debug a breakpoint for a while), the BeginSend or BeginReceive or their AsyncCallback will throw exception or set a SocketErrorCode to tell me the connection was notconnected or reset. According to the server side error code can know the connection was reset by client side. However, I never call socket::disconnect or close, the disconnect is done by .net itself, thit is unwanted. It make debug impractical.

I thought, if the other peer paused, the BeginSend and BeginRecv's AsyncCallback {EndReceive(ar) or EndSend(ar)}should blocks until the peer resumes execution because I have not set keep alive or any timeout. However, it is not, it seems .net has a timeout to close the connection.

How to avoid this?

Comment: That's just how it is, when you debug socket applications, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, server code actively disconnect after a timeout somewhere I haven't noticed and the error code returned by socket.read are miss checked, so I blame on .net, I am sorry. .net are correct as I thought, the recv callback blocks on EndReceive(ar) until peer side resume execution to release the sending data